# Drawbacks of using embedded Spark in Application

Tags: apache-spark, application-server

I have a use case where in I launch local spark (embedded) inside an application server rather than going for spark rest job server or kernel. Because former(embedded spark) has very low latency compared to other. I am interested in

- Drawbacks of this approach if there are any.
- Can same be used in production?

P.S. Low latency is priority here.

EDIT: Size of the data being processed for most of the cases will be less than 100mb.

Comment: Whats the size of the data being processed?  Running Spark locally is usually not the intended use of Spark.

Comment: @JoeWiden Please refer to my edit.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is a drawback at all. If you have a look at the implementation of the [Hive Thriftserver](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-the-thrift-jdbcodbc-server) within the Spark project itself, they also manage `SQLContext` etc, in the [Hive Server](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver) process. This is especially the case, if the amount of data is small and the driver can handle it easily. So I would also see this as a hint, that this okay for production use.

But I totally agree, the documentation or advice in general how to integrate spark into interactive customer-facing application is lacking behind the information for BigData pipelines.